# what is the difference between StackExchange.Redis and NRedisStack packages?

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

The official [redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/connect/clients/dotnet/) for dotnet recommends the package [NRedisStack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NRedisStack) in the installation guide, and the NRedisStack docs says the following:

> This project builds on StackExchange.Redis

But there is also the very popular package StackExchange.Redis which is widely used yet.

I tried to find a comparison between them but didn't succeed, so when should I use each one of them and what is the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other? is StachExchange.Redis obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NuGet, if you switch to the Dependencies tab in NRedisStack, you'll see that it has StackExchange.Redis as a dependency. The latter sits on top of the former, so the question isn't "NRedisStack versus StackExchange.Redis", but rather: "vanilla StackExchange.Redis vs StackExchange.Redis plus NRedisStack".

StackExchange.Redis is absolutely **not** obsolete - it is being actively used either way in both options here!

I genuinely don't know in detail what additional things NRedisStack adds, but I *believe* it is mostly support for some "modules" (RediSearch, perhaps). The question, then, is: are you using those modules? Most core redis functionality should already be available in StackExchange.Redis without the extra layer.

Perhaps asking for an exact list of the features added would be a reasonable issue to log with NRedisStack.